# Python - Trying to extract files from one location to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date

I am trying to pull a set of files from a server and store in one of the folders in my local. The below code works well for this task. However if any of the files are empty it stops at that point and does not continue further.

```
list_ = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(file_, index_col=None, delim_whitespace=True)
        list_.append(df)
        temp = pd.concat(list_)
    except EmptyDataError:
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        return df
```

Could anyone advice as to how could I by-pass these empty files  and continue to extract the other files from the server. Thanks

**Update:**

Given below is the function I am trying to perform

```
list_ = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(file_, index_col=None, header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
        list_.append(df)
        temp = pd.concat(list_)
    except pd.errors.EmptyDataError:
        continue
df_v1 = [pd.read_csv(fp, delim_whitespace=True).assign(FileName=os.path.basename(fp)) for fp in allFiles]  <<-- Error thrown on this line as per trackback
df = pd.concat(df_v1, ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

Trackback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/venv/try.py", line 102, in <module>
s3_func("stores","store_a", "2018-10-03", "2018-10-05")
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/venv/try.py", line 86, in s3_func
df_v1 = [pd.read_csv(fp, delim_whitespace=True).assign(FileName=os.path.basename(fp)) for fp in allFiles]
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/venv/try.py", line 86, in <listcomp>
df_v1 = [pd.read_csv(fp, delim_whitespace=True).assign(FileName=os.path.basename(fp)) for fp in allFiles]
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 678, in parser_f
return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 440, in _read
parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 787, in __init__
self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1014, in _make_engine
self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1708, in __init__
self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 542, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

Comment: Why do you have a `return` in there? Presumably this is part of a function, but it doesn't make sense that you throw away any successful loops, initialise an empty dataframe and return it on an exception

Comment: @roganjosh, thanks my bad. I modified the code which is similar to the code suggested by Hristiyan below but it still throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is exiting upon reaching `return` condition.
If you want to continue the iteration if exception occurs you can do the following:

```
list_ = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(file_, index_col=None, delim_whitespace=True)
        list_.append(df)
        temp = pd.concat(list_)
    except EmptyDataError:
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        continue  # Changed return with continue, since return breaks the loop.
```

Also I see that you are creating empty data frame on exception. What you do with that empty data frame? Do you need it for future usage?

If you would need the empty data frames in future, consider appending them to the list as well

```
except EmptyDataError:
            df = pd.DataFrame()
            list_.append(df)  # Appending empty dataframes to the list
            continue
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I modified the code as per your suggestion but it still throws an error when an empty file is there

Comment: Try removing `df = pd.DataFrame()` and `list_.append(df)` and leave only `continue`. It would pass instead of throwing exception, but empty dataframes will not be saved.

Comment: tried this as well but this throws the same error.Just wanted to confirm "EmptyDataError" is  from  "pd.errors.EmptyDataError" library right.

Comment: Could you please share the traceback?

Comment: I have updated my initial message with the trackback message.. Tnx